# jQuery ajax load event not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-load

I am attempting to load in another part of a site into a div using jQuery's ajax's load event. Long story short--it isn't loading anything. I have tried using a link with a click event (for testing purposes).

Here is the jQuery code:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#content-load-ajax').load('http://http://chemswap.com/register.php');
        </script>
    });
```

I am trying to place registrar.php into the the div ID content-load-ajax. When the page loads it fails to load the php page in.

More information:
*URL: http://www.chemswap.com/wordpress/registrar/ (the page that is loading in there is in an iFrame)

*I am running this on WordPress.

*registrar.php is custom software developed for the clients older site. It references many different modules and such. We just want to load registrar.php directly into the current page.

If anyone knows why this isn't working please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The `$(document).ready() ...` is **also** Javascript, so you need to put your `<script>` tag around that too.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#content-load-ajax').load('http://http://chemswap.com/register.php');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I did that and it is still not loading the content in.